# Change src of embedded .txt

Tags: javascript, html, css

orientating on the quizshow jeopardy I´m trying to implement a page that shows columns (categories) and rows (value) of divs, that when clicked on will popup different questions or images.

The function looks like this:

```
    function popup(q) {
        var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
        document.getElementById("src").src = q;
        popup.classList.toggle("show");
    }
```

And is called like this:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="popup('question1.txt')">    
    Category 1 <br/> 50 
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
        <iframe id="src">
        </iframe>
    </span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="popup('question2.txt')">    
    Category 2 <br/> 50 
</div>
```

(for further css for .popup, .popuptext, etc. look here: how TO - popup) The mayor change I made in the css is the position of .popuptext (plus adjusting some values of course)

```
position: fixed;
```

This works fine for .txt, however I also want to embed pictures which ends in really ugly scenarios with iframe. I found, this can be avoided by replacing the iframe by embed:-->

```
<div class="popup" onclick="popup('picture1.jpg')"> 
    Category 1 <br/> 50 
    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
        <embed id="src" />
    </span>
</div>

<div class="popup" onclick="popup('picture2.jpg')"> 
    Category 2<br/> 50 
</div>
```

So iframe works for .txt (but it won't give me proper img-resizing), while embed works for images, but not for .txt files (the text shown will always be the content of the .txt file I called first).

I know I can workaround this using 2 functions and giving the second div other class and id-names, that relate to the second function.
I dont want to do this, since the position handling of the popups is really annoying.

Any suggestions, how to handle this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps worth looking into the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset api, so you can attach the name of the file to be opened to the div. Once done, you could use attachEventListener (rather than inline javascript) to fire the desired function. The function can then extract the info you want to open with the popup function. By using the dataset api, you then have an easy way of changing the data that will be used by the popup function, rather than having a hardcoded call to popup.

Comment: tried a bit to follow your hint...in the end i learned quiet a lot, but i wasnt able to get more by the .addEventListener method, than i already got. The solution would rather be changing the embed/iframe elements to something, that does both (imgs and txts). Thanks though. Will try a workaround with 2 functions now.